# Bind element and its children in jQuery

Tags: jquery, bind, children

I'd like to bind an event to an element and its children. What is the best way to do this?

```
$(element).bind('click', function(event) {
    doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(element).bind('click', function(event) {
    doSomething();
}).children().bind("click",function(event){
    // code to handle children click here
    event.stopPropagation(); // if you don't want event to bubble up
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will do just that.

Look in the event's `target` field to find out which actual child node saw the event.