# Binding click events for all children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to bind click events for children of an element like so:

```
$('#A').children().bind('click',function () {
    console.log('Hello');
});
```

The HTML is

```
<select id='A'>
    <option val='1'>One</option>
    <option val='2'>Two</option>
</select>
```

I've checked out other questions in stackoverflow, such as [Bind element and its children in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728178/bind-element-and-its-children-in-jquery) and the same method is mentioned everywhere. Is there something wrong here?

**Edit**

I understand that there is a change event available, but, consider the scenario where there is a need to trigger the change event when I select the same option which is selected.

Change only works when options are changed from `One` to `Two` or vice versa, but what if I select the same option, i.e: Changing from `Two` to `Two` itself?

Comment: go with `$('#A').bind('change',..`

Comment: @AmitSoni `change` only fires if you click on a different option than the current selection.

Comment: select => option may no click. bind event to select

Comment: Are you adding options dynamically? Your binding only applies to children that are there when you run that code.

Comment: If that's the case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: $('#A option').bind('click'

Comment: @Barmar: Options are not added dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other replies suggest solutions to the problem. The reason that your code may not work in a strict browser is that the [click event is not defined](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/click-not-working-on-option-in-chrome) for an option element. You can use the change event or if you really need to handle click, you should not use the native select element.

Comment: Thanks you for clarifying that. Just needed to know if there is another way to detect when a change is made(see question for recent Edit)

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/a/14446179/549895 has exactly what you are looking for. Though I would think twice before doing this, because as a user I wont expect something to change if I select the same thing again. But then again, you would have a better grip on your usecase than I :).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `change()` event instead of `click` and do not need to bind with `option`. The event will trigger whenever the option selection is changed by **clicking** the option.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/LYuuu/1/)**

```
$('#A').bind('change',function () {
    console.log('Hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event for `select` element here since `.change()` event will be fired when you change the `option`:

```
$('#A').on('change',function () {
    console.log('Hello');
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the behaviour you wanted? **http://jsfiddle.net/P97ML/**

```
$('#A').bind('change',function () {
    console.log('Hello');
});
```

Comment: Well, I have tried the change element, but, I have a scenario where I need to trigger an event when I select the option, which is already selected. So, I tried to manually add it using the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with change event of `select`.

Do like this:

```
$('#A').on('change',function () {
    console.log($(this).val()); // log selected option value
});
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the 3 previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly (*will work in most of the cases*) but that is not the case with `options` inside `select`

you need to use change event , and if you want to get reference to the selected option you can use 
`:selected`

```
$('#A').bind('change',function () {
    console.log('Hello');
    var $selectedOption = $("option:selected",this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mouse events aren't triggered on the individual options, they're triggered on the select menu as a whole. So do:

```
$('#A').click(function() {
    alert('Hello');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jc8Gq/1/)